# A woman and two children travel to other world aided by 'Notus' bushes

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a fantasy book (it might have been a novella) I partially read as a child/teen, around 1970–77 from the school library.

A woman becomes a governess or companion to two children, brother and sister, I think. The setting may not have been Earth.

Following the children (at night?), she find some sort of garden with magical or alien plants or bushes where they play. They take her through them into a mysterious dream or parallel world.

The name of the plant is something like "**Notus**", after the south wind, and possibly they exuded some hallucinatory drug or gas.

The children's father also figures. There may be a romantic subtext, but I didn't finish the book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is very likely to be *[Dread Companion](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11110)*, a novel by Andre Norton, first published in 1970.

The main character is called Kilda c’Rhyn, who, wanting to leave her home planet, finds a job as a child attendant for a wealthy family. The mother and her two children are leaving Chalox to travel to Dylan, the planet where their father is stationed. When they arrive on the planet, Kilda and the children pass through a gateway into a strange world, which indeed features magic trees called the "notus":

> Thus I reached the first of the notus trees. There was more than one —
> in fact, a small grove of them. And I stood breathing deeply,
> rejoicing in the feeling of headiness and well-being.

Comment: Oh yes, that seems to be it. I recognise the MC had an odd name and the story had a strange not quite sci-fi/fantasy/horror vibe. I'd had no success Googling notus trees. From the iffy reviews on Goodreads I'm not surprised I didn't finish it. Maybe I'll try again. Thanks.

Comment: I did think of this, but I didn't remember the notus trees.